# how to create an incrementing variable in a table using existing variable in table

Tags: mysql, database, increment

I I wonder if someone could help me to add incrementing variables (columns) to a table I created in MySQL using already existing columns. I was able to create a table of starting pitcher logs that include the starting pitchers' runs allowed, earned runs, innings pitched, home runs allowed, hits, etc., for each game they started over the course of many seasons. I made it out of the retrosheet database of MLB data in MySQL that I set up. The code I used to set up this table from the database is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS starting_pitcher_game_log;
CREATE TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log
SELECT a .PIT_ID
, g.GAME_ID
, IF(g.WIN_PIT_ID = a.PIT_ID,1,0) AS W
, IF(g.LOSE_PIT_ID = a.PIT_ID,1,0) AS L
, a.IP
, a.BFP
, a.H
, a.R
, a.ER
, a.HR
, a.BB
, a.K
, a.IBB
, a.HBP
, a.WP
, a.BALK
FROM (
    SELECT PIT_ID , GAME_ID
    , SUM(EVENT_OUTS_CT)/3 AS IP
    , SUM(IF(BAT_EVENT_FL = "T",1,0)) AS BFP
    , SUM(IF(H_CD>0,1,0)) AS H
    , SUM(IF(BAT_FATE_ID>3,1,0)) AS R
    , SUM(IF(BAT_FATE_ID IN (4,6),1,0)) AS ER
    , SUM(IF(H_CD = 4,1,0)) AS HR
    , SUM(IF(EVENT_CD IN (14,15),1,0)) AS BB
    , SUM(IF(EVENT_CD = 3,1,0)) AS K
    , SUM(IF(EVENT_CD = 15,1,0)) AS IBB
    , SUM(IF(EVENT_CD = 16,1,0)) AS HBP
    , SUM(IF(EVENT_CD = 9,1,0)) AS WP
    , SUM(IF(EVENT_CD = 11,1,0)) AS BALK
    FROM retrosheet.events
    WHERE PIT_START_FL = "T"
    GROUP BY PIT_ID,GAME_ID
) AS a
INNER JOIN retrosheet.games AS g
ON a.GAME_ID = g.GAME_ID;
```

So, again, what I want to do at this point is add columns to this table, each reflecting season-to-date cumulative sums of the variables already in the the table (for earned runs, innings pitched, etc.). The variables in this table show the values for each of those variables for that given game. Using innings pitched, for example, with each subsequent pitcher's start of a given season, I'd like to reflect the running total of innings pitched by that starting pitcher from the beginning of the season through any game they played that season.

Can someone help me with the code to create these incrementing variables (columns) reflecting these season-to-date values for each game using the values in the columns that already exist in this table?

I am starting to learn MySQL, but my knowledge is still very lacking.

This is what I've come up with so far

```
SET ytd_ip:= 0;
UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log
SELECT
IF(@prevgame_yr != year_id,ip,@ytd_ip+ip) AS ip,
@prevgame_yr=year_id
FROM retrosheet.starting_pitcher_game_log
WHERE table_id=starting_pitcher_game_log
```

I know it's not right, but don't know how to change it to make it work

Help would go a long way.

Clarification: Thank you for highlighting these options. As I read through them, I'm realizing that I should clarify what the table looks like and what I'm looking for more clearly. I have a column for PITCHER_ID; a column for GAME_ID;  and columns for innings pitched,  earned runs,  walks allowed,  etc that contain the value for each  variable for each game (e.g., innings pitched for the game). In the season-to-date column(s) that I'd like to create, I'd like to sort it by the pitcher-ID column and the GAMES_ID column such that the values will increment up for the same pitcher across each game in order of date of the game that the pitcher played in for a given season. How can I make sure the value for a particular game in the season-to-date column for innings pitched is the sum of innings pitched for a given pitcher across all the games he has played in up to that game for that season + the innings pitched in that game; and then allow for the same rule to apply to data that will be added for future games?

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' DROP 'id_increment';

ALTER TABLE 'table_name' ADD 'id_increment' INT NULL, ADD UNIQUE ('id_increment') ;

ALTER TABLE 'table_name' CHANGE 'id_increment' 'id_increment' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```